# Run selenium with chrome driver on centos without Gui

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver

I write some code with python selenium using chrome driver as web driver. When I run code in my system ( mac os ), the code works. Chrome browser was opened, and selenium works correctly. But when I want to run my code in Centos 7 without GUI, selenium can't match with web driver and run the code. Although I install google-chrome-stable and use the same web driver for it, selenium can't run web driver.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path=chromedrive75)
```

So, I don't know how to fix the code and running on my centos operating system.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

@Vahid, please check the chrome web browser version which is compatible with server, also try running in headless mode.

Comment: I checked several version of chrome web drive, from 73 to 76. with and without options ( headless mode ). not working.

Comment: @Vahid what is the chromedriver version. You can get it by typing chromedriver --version. I believe it is not compatible. please go through https://codar.club/blogs/centos7-installation-python-3-selenium-chrome-chrome-driver-details.html